# How to stop a Python program after some arbitrary timeout

Tags: python

Just for instance, this code is working

```
import urllib

image = urllib.URLopener()
file_ = 1
name = 1
for i in range(1,1000):
    try:
        image.retrieve("http://mangawriter.com/pics/pic"+str(file_)+".jpeg","pic"+str(name)+".jpeg")
        print "save file %s" %file_ 
        name += 1
        file_ += 1
    except IOError:
        file_ += 1
```

How could I make it stop after some time was spent, even if the code is still being ran? Please, help me to figure it out.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't stop at the end? In fact, how do you know it gets to the end?

Comment: you have an indent error.. also, why are you looping over `i` but incrementing `name` manually?  you can just loop over `name`.

Comment: This is only an example for retrieving 3 pictures with different names, what if there are lots of pictures?

I purposely made ​​the example as above.

Comment: I just want to know how to stop the program, for example above

Comment: but in your example, you're retrieving 999 times not 3 times.

Comment: can you rewrite the above example, please :)

Comment: 999 times it's just an example, what if there are hundreds of pictures with different image names with the last digit is uncertain and halting code themselves?

Comment: So, you are running the program with these values and it does not end after downloading the 999th image?

Comment: @brandizzi No, 1000 is only indicative, because I do not know how many images there are in these directories are

Comment: If you run the program with, let us say, `range(1, 4)`, does it stop?

Comment: @brandizzi of course will stop, I know. but I just want to say the code above is just an example, I intend going to save more images with different names and numbers by the number of images that a lot more.

Comment: So, you want to terminate the program after some time, have it download all images or not. Am I right now?

Comment: @brandizzi yes more than once, I want to terminate the program when the request has timed out several times code as above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing) module, which generates new processes (not threads) for parallelizing tasks.

How to do it? First, the actual download code should be put in a function:

```
import urllib
import multiprocessing
import time

def download_images():
    image = urllib.URLopener()
    file_ = 1
    name = 1
    for i in range(1,1000):
        try:
            image.retrieve("http://mangawriter.com/pics/pic"+str(file_)+".jpeg","pic"+str(name)+".jpeg")
            print "save file %s" %file_ 
            name += 1
            file_ += 1
        except IOError:
            file_ += 1
```

Now, we create a new `multiprocessing.Process` object, passing the function above as its target. This object will start a process just to execute this function:

```
downloader = multiprocessing.Process(target=download_images)
```

Once we have created the process object, just call its `start()` method. This will start a process that will run in parallel:

```
downloader.start()
```

Since it is running in parallel, the main program keeps executing. Now, we define a timeout and sleep for the time of this timeout. In the example below, the timeout is 15 seconds:

```
timeout = 15
time.sleep(timeout)
```

Once the timeout ends, just terminate the downloader process:

```
downloader.terminate()
```

The full program can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/u9VGUiMj).

Comment: If this is a good solution to your problem, you should click the checkbox next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best but a usable way:

You can spawn a child thread using `threading` module to do this, and, set an time.sleep in your main thread, so when time is out, you can kill the child thread.

**EDIT**: just something like this:

```
import threading
import urllib

def child(file_, name):
    try:
        image = urllib.URLopener()
        image.retrieve("http://mangawriter.com/pics/pic"+str(file_)+".jpeg","pic"+str(name)+".jpeg")
        print "save file %s" % file_
    except IOError:
        pass

file_ = 1
name = 1
for i in range(1,1000):
    t = threading.Thread(target = child, args = (file_, name))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join(timeout = 10)
    file_ += 1
    name += 1
```

Comment: Okay. The timeout defined can be changed, now I'm killing the child thread after 10 seconds.

Comment: Do you want your whole process to terminate after a specific timeout, or the timeout is per thread(for every time trying to fetch a new image)?

Comment: don't you think this might hammer the server?  you might not get any images downloaded if the server thinks you're trying to DOS it ..

Answer (score 0):

This one really works for me and it is very simple. Suppose that we want stop after 25 seconds.

```
    import timeit #we will need the command default_timer() that checks the actual time
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    while timeit.default_timer()-start<=25:
         "you code here"
```